# Django form fields dynamic subclassing

Tags: python, django, forms, class, dynamic

I'm trying to develop mechanism to dynamically create set of Django Form Fields.

While experimenting, I encounter strange behavior, and I'd like to know, if it worth to worry about.

Here the code:

```
In [139]: from django import forms

In [140]: MyFieldDynamic = type('MyFieldDynamic', (forms.CharField,), {})

In [141]:   1 class MyField(forms.CharField):
            2     pass

In [142]: MyFieldDynamic.mro()
Out[142]: 
[django.utils.deprecation.MyFieldDynamic,
 django.forms.fields.CharField,
 django.forms.fields.Field,
 object]

In [143]: MyField.mro()
Out[143]: 
[__main__.MyField,
 django.forms.fields.CharField,
 django.forms.fields.Field,
 object]
```

As you see if class created using `type`, its first superclass is `django.utils.deprecation.MyFieldDynamic`. What's wrong with this thing?

And a bit more broader question - is it possible at all, what I'm trying to do - create form fields at runtime? Maybe there are some resources, I skipped?

Edit:

Python:

```
2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) \n[GCC 4.8.2]
```

Django:

```
(1, 8, 3, 'final', 0)
```

Comment: what python version are you using?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? What behaviour do you need that can only be done by dynamically creating subclasses at runtime?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, there is variable length set of datatypes with their own restrictions, which I need to map to Django Fields, and then, using those fields generate forms.